# What does "go red ring" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

I've come across it in the first episode of the fifth season of *the Walking Dead*. Here is the context:

> Scientist: Even if I told you all,
>
> even if I provided step-by-step instructions
>
> complete with illustrations and a well-composed FAQ
>
> and I went **red-ring**...
>
> the cure would still die with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[YourDictionary.com](https://www.yourdictionary.com/red-ring) defines Red-ring as

> **Red-ring (verb):**
> (video games, of an Xbox 360 games console) To suffer a general hardware fault, the red ring of death.
>
> Example: My 360 red-ringed and I had to ship it to Texas to get it fixed.

I believe the Scientist relates his own future demise to that of a general hardware fault of a games console.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the answer by @Seowjooheng Singapore

Here is a picture of a red ring indicating an error condition on an Xbox 360.

[image]